# Why does select @@version gives 2005 when I installed 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Apparently I see about in SQL Server Management Studio and I saw 2008 version.

But when I perform

```
select @@version
```

I am seeing version 2005

I think this explains why my stored procedure could run on another computer whose compatibility level=100

Comment: You might have installed SQL Server **Management Studio** from the 2008 version, but the **SQL Server ENGINE** you're connecting to is still a **2005** version..... just because you install the new Mgmt Studio doesn't mean your actual **server engine** is upgraded ....

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have installed the Studio version of 2008, this is what you will see if you login to the server for instance.

However, the @@version command shows you what is actually used under the hood. Here you still use the engine of 2005.

Comment: so any compatibility issues you had with stored procedures? As my stored procedure can run on a database with compatibility of 100 but gives incorrect syntax at p_storedproc for a compatibility of 90

Comment: may i know how can i upgrade my actual server engine?

Comment: All the information should be available here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677622(v=sql.100).aspx